# push object to array with another object as a property

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create json string based on datatable rows. Source below works well , but sometimes i dont have AddressDetails object and I want to not set this. How to add condition to this code ( if selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails=null not set DeliveryAddressDetails )

```
var returnItems=[];
                data.each(function() {
                    var rowIndex = $dataTable.fnGetPosition(this);
                    var selectedRow = $dataTable.fnGetData(rowIndex);
                    returnItems.push(
                        {
                            DeliveryAddress: selectedRow.DeliveryAddress,
                            Extension: selectedRow.Extension,
                            IsCourier: selectedRow.IsCourier,
                            Quantity: selectedRow.Quantity,
                            DeliveryAddressDetails: {
                                AddressDestinationDescription: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationDescription,
                                AddressDestinationDetailId: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationDetailId,
                                AddressDestinationName: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationName,
                                AddressLine1: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine1,
                                AddressLine2: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine2,
                                AddressLine3: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine3,
                                CityName: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.CityName,
                                PhoneNumber: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.PhoneNumber,
                                ZipCode: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.ZipCode
                            }
                        });
                });
        $("#myJson").val(JSON.stringify(returnItems));
```

thnx for help

Comment: `if(selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails != null || selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails != undefine) { // push into array}`

Comment: Create empty entity for returnItems and use jquery extend for push object is easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the object first, and then add that property conditionally

```
var returnItems = [];
data.each(function() {
    var rowIndex = $dataTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    var selectedRow = $dataTable.fnGetData(rowIndex);
    var obj = {
        DeliveryAddress: selectedRow.DeliveryAddress,
        Extension: selectedRow.Extension,
        IsCourier: selectedRow.IsCourier,
        Quantity: selectedRow.Quantity
    }
    if ( DeliveryAddressDetails !== null ) { // or typeof ** == "object"
        obj.DeliveryAddressDetails = {
            AddressDestinationDescription: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationDescription,
            AddressDestinationDetailId: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationDetailId,
            AddressDestinationName: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressDestinationName,
            AddressLine1: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine1,
            AddressLine2: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine2,
            AddressLine3: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.AddressLine3,
            CityName: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.CityName,
            PhoneNumber: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.PhoneNumber,
            ZipCode: selectedRow.DeliveryAddressDetails.ZipCode
        }
    }
    returnItems.push();
});

$("#myJson").val(JSON.stringify(returnItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally set fields in an object, you'll have to add it after the initial creation.

```
var objToPush = { /* obj creation */ };
conditionToTest && (objToPush[someKey] = someValue);
```

The `conditionToTest && doSomething` pattern will only trigger if the condition is true. It's equivalent to:

```
var objToPush = { /* obj creation */ };

if (conditionToTest)
    (objToPush[someKey] = someValue);
```

but a bit more concise.